# Limit a description field to 500 words in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form in which there is a field for description.
I want to give a validation in that description field which doesn't allow the user to enter more than 500 words.. not character. 
is there a good gem for this in rails.

Comment: https://github.com/abitdodgy/words_counted Note: I have never used this, just a quick search turned it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if there is a gem for this. But it can be done with a few lines of code:

```
validate :description_maximum_500_words

private
def description_maximum_500_words
  if description.split.size > 500
    errors.add(:description, 'contains more then 500 words')
  end
end
```

Comment: i dont know how to do this.. im already having one validate statement..
validate :description, presence: true

and also in the method..what is description..

Comment: Just add all the code to your class. The `validate` to the top, the private method to the bottom. Read more about validators methods: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods